# Flutter BackgroundLocation.getLocationUpdates not working

Tags: flutter, background, location, tracking

I am trying to create real-time distance tracking with Flutter. for that I am using the background_location package and I was working fine in 1. xx versions. but after I upgraded my flutter version to 2. xx it won't work.
Here are the relevant parts of the code.

```
 Future<void> startLocationUpdate() async {
  FirebaseService.logtoGPSData('=================================================================================================');
  FirebaseService.logtoGPSData('=================================== GPS based Distance tracking is on ===========================');
  FirebaseService.logtoGPSData('=================================================================================================');
  oldPosition2 = Location(
      longitude: CustomParameters.currentPosition.longitude,
      latitude: CustomParameters.currentPosition.latitude);
  isWaited = false;

  var permission = await Permission.locationAlways.isGranted;
  if (!permission) {
    var permisisonState = await Permission.locationAlways.request();
    if (permisisonState.isDenied || permisisonState.isPermanentlyDenied) {
      //showToast(context,"Permission has not granted to use location.");
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  } else {
    showToast(context, "Permission has not granted to use location.");
    print("Point 6");
  }

  BackgroundLocation.setAndroidConfiguration(2000);
  await BackgroundLocation.setAndroidNotification(
    title: "Background location",
    message: "Background location in progress",
    icon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
  );
  print("Point 8");
  await BackgroundLocation.startLocationService(distanceFilter: 20);

  BackgroundLocation.getLocationUpdates((location) {
    print('Inside updates');
    try {
      CustomParameters.currentPosition = location;
      LatLng pos = LatLng(location.latitude!, location.longitude!);
      var rotation = MapKitHelperService.getMarkerRotation(
          oldPosition2.latitude,
          oldPosition2.longitude,
          pos.latitude,
          pos.longitude);
      setState(() {
        accuracy = location.accuracy!.toStringAsFixed(0);
        infoPanel = "On Trip";
        totalSpeed = location.speed!;
        var oldPos = oldPosition2 ?? location;
        totalDistance = totalDistance +
            calculateDistance(oldPos.latitude, oldPos.longitude,
                location.latitude, location.longitude);
        print("distance  $totalDistance");
      });
      oldPosition2 = location;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error in updates ${e}');
    }
  });
  print("End Of init.");
}

double calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  var p = 0.017453292519943295;
  var c = cos;
  var a = 0.5 -
      c((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
      c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p)) / 2;
  return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
}

double CalDistance(Location pos1, Location pos2, DistanceType type) {
  double R = (type == DistanceType.Miles) ? 3960 : 6371;
  double dLat = toRadian(pos2.latitude! - pos1.latitude!);
  double dLon = toRadian(pos2.longitude! - pos1.longitude!);
  double a = sin(dLat / 2) * sin(dLat / 2) +
      cos(toRadian(pos1.latitude!)) *
          cos(toRadian(pos2.latitude!)) *
          sin(dLon / 2) *
          sin(dLon / 2);
  double c = 2 * asin(min(1, sqrt(a)));
  double d = R * c;
  return d;
}

double toRadian(double val) {
  return (pi / 180) * val;
}
```

This method gets called inside a button click of the UI widget

```
doRide() async {
if (CustomParameters.homeTabPositionStream != null) {
  await CustomParameters.homeTabPositionStream!.cancel();
}
await startLocationUpdate();


 ............................
```

This Is my Flutter Doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1415], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - developed for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

These are the added Permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

 background_location: ^0.8.1
 permission_handler: ^8.3.0
```

Program Prints

1. "Point 6"
2. "Point 8"
3. "End Of init."
4. but never get prints the "Inside updates"

but it shows Background location was tracked in the info section.
Location Permission set to Allow all the time

Can anyone please help me to get out of this mud? tried everything I know for the last 5 days
Thanks